# swiftでのダウンキャストについて

Tags: swift

ダウンキャストについてお尋ねします。
以下のようにクラスを継承し、

```
class CNMutableGroupKai: CNMutableGroup {
    var icon: String = ""
}
```

とし

```
var groupData = group.mutableCopy() as! CNMutableGroupKai
```

とダウンキャストしたいのですが失敗してしまいます。

おそらくは根本的なことを間違っていると思います。
ご教授をお願いできませんでしょうか。

Comment: `group`はどのような定義で、どのような値が入っているのですか?それと「失敗してしまいます」の内容もご説明ください。ビルド時のエラーでしょうか、実行時のエラーでしょうか?

Comment: 説明不足で申し訳ありません。group:CNGroupです。また失敗は実行時です。下の方の回答から根本的な間違いに気づきました。回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

`mutableCopy()`はそのインスタンスの複製を作ります。`CNMutableGroupKai`では、`mutableCopy()`をオーバーライドしていないので、親クラスの実装が呼ばれ、`CNMutableGroup`の複製を作ります。

実体が`CNMutableGroup`であるものを、`CNMutableGroupKai`へキャストするのは不正ですので、`as!`でクラッシュするのは正当な挙動になります。

対処法としては、`mutableCopy()`を実装するということが考えられますが、

```
class CNMutableGroupKai: CNMutableGroup {
    var icon: String = ""

    override func mutableCopy() -> AnyObject {
        let copy = CNMutableGroupKai()
        // identifierは読み取り専用なのでコピーできない
        // copy.identifier = self.identifier
        copy.name = self.name
        copy.icon = self.icon
        return copy
    }
}
```

そもそも、`CNMutableGroup`に独自のプロパティを追加しても、それは`CNContactStore`で保存することもできません（`CNMutableGroup`はグループ情報を操作して、保存するためにあるクラスです）し、推奨されない行為のように思えます。

連絡帳グループにそれを示すアイコンを持たせたい場合、Contactsフレームワークのクラスを拡張するよりも、ラッパーとなる構造体などを作った方が良いのではないでしょうか。

```
struct GroupData {
    var icon: UIImage
    var group: CNGroup
}
```

Comment: 大変わかりやすい回答ありがとうざいます。おっしゃる通り最終的に保存ができないためこの方法はバツですね。ご提案の方法で考え直します。回答ありがとうございました。